# Nocopy minimal example?

Tags: go, struct, mutex

I've been trying to get a `noCopy` directive to work for one of my own structs, but I cannot get `go vet` to detect it.

I can get it to detect copying of `sync.WaitGroup`, and `sync.Mutex`, but not my own struct. [This test file](https://golang.org/src/cmd/vet/testdata/copylock.go) in the vet source doesn't even trigger with my `go vet`.

Or well, it finds some of the errors:

```
# command-line-arguments
./govet.go:56:6: no new variables on left side of :=
./govet.go:110:17: unsafe.Sizeof(mu) evaluated but not used
./govet.go:111:18: unsafe.Sizeof(mu) evaluated but not used
./govet.go:112:10: unsafe.Sizeof(mu) evaluated but not used
```

but the copylock detection doesn't find anything.

Did something change in `go vet` since [this discussion](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8005#issuecomment-190753527) at 1.4? I'm running `go version go1.11 darwin/amd64`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, copying locks is properly detected by `go vet`. Example:

```
type My struct {
    l sync.Mutex
}
```

Usage:

```
func main() {
    m := My{}
    m2 := m
    fmt.Println(m2)
}
```

Running `go vet`, the output is:

```
./play.go:25: assignment copies lock value to m2: main.My contains sync.Mutex
./play.go:26: call of fmt.Println copies lock value: main.My contains sync.Mutex
```

So both cases (assigning and passing to `fmt.Println()`) were detected.

This also means that the easiest way to make your struct a target of vet when copied, simply add a field of type `sync.Mutex`. This is a ready solution, although it consumes memory (`sync.Mutex` is not a zero-size struct). It doesn't matter whether you use this mutex or not (we didn't use it in the example above).

In the discussion you referenced Rob Pike suggests to create a type:

```
type noCopy struct{}
func (*noCopy) Lock() {}
```

And use a field of this type (either regular or embedded) to mark a struct non-copiable (and so make `go vet` scream if that happens).

I don't know if this has ever worked, but currently it doesn't, because `go vet` checks for the [`sync.Locker`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Locker) interface, which also has an `Unlock()` method:

```
type Locker interface {
        Lock()
        Unlock()
}
```

So if we create a `noCopy` type that implements `sync.Locker` (more precisely its pointer type), that will work:

```
type noCopy struct{}

func (*noCopy) Lock()   {}
func (*noCopy) Unlock() {}

type By struct {
    noCopy noCopy
}
```

Testing it:

```
func main() {
    b := By{}
    b2 := b
    fmt.Println(b2)
}
```

Running `go vet`:

```
./play.go:29: assignment copies lock value to b2: main.By contains main.noCopy
./play.go:30: call of fmt.Println copies lock value: main.By contains main.noCopy
```

Here are some changes related to `go vet` and `noCopy`:

[Go 1.7](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#cmd_vet)

[Go 1.8](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#tool_vet)

Comment: I have a vague memory of there being an `Unlocker` interface as well. If so, maybe they merged the two, and added the extra function to `Locker`?

Comment: @FilipHaglund I doubt they removed `Unlocker`: it's not currently in the standard lib, and removing it would cause backward incompatibility (and hence breaking Go 1's compatibility promise). I added some links regarding `go vet` and `nocopy`.

Comment: Maybe the interface wasn't public before? Idk. Nice digging anyways, thanks for the answer.